# IndexerPostProcessor are not working after restart for JournalArticle liferay 7

Tags: indexing, liferay-7

for some specific search queries i have created JournalArticle IndexerPostProcessor which is not working when Liferay server is restart.

I have added that indexes class in my service api project. I am using lifeay 7 ce GA4 version.

I have searched in liferay community and found bug is fixed in later version.[LR Issue link](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-85702)

Any help, workaround would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You'll either have to identify the changes and backport the fix to your version or (preferably) update. You're on an old version - at the very least you should [patch](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/security-patches-for-liferay-portal-6-2-7-0-and-7-1) (which will require an upgrade to the latest 7.0 GA as well).

Comment: Thanks Olaf, This will take a little long time and we will plan for it for sure as we are constantly attacked by mining malware (kinshig). any temporary workaround?